# python keyword string formatting with '%' confusing error : unsupported format character 'p'

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have the following setup

```
cred_dict={'admin_id':'user','admin_password':'pass'}

cred_template='-id=%(admin_id) -pa=%(admin_password)'
```

When I try

```
cred_template % cred_dict
```

I get

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'p' (0x70) at index 17
```

and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a crucial element: the formatting *type* indicator:

```
cred_template='-id=%(admin_id)s -pa=%(admin_password)s'
#                             ^                      ^
```

The `s` indicates you want to format the values as strings. Without those indicators, Python keeps looking for the type and finds the letter `p` (from `-pa`) and that's not a valid type indicator.

Demo:

```
>>> cred_dict={'admin_id':'user','admin_password':'pass'}
>>> cred_template='-id=%(admin_id)s -pa=%(admin_password)s'
>>> cred_template % cred_dict
'-id=user -pa=pass'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which you may find easier and less error prone:

```
cred_dict={'admin_id':'user','admin_password':'pass'}    
cred_template='-id={admin_id} -pa={admin_password}'
print(cred_template.format(**cred_dict))

-id=user -pa=pass
```